# LEFT JOIN in Rails ActiveRecord without conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ProductSupplierInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_supplier_info_packings, :inverse_of => :product_supplier_info
  belongs_to :supplier
end

class ProductSupplierInfoPacking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_supplier_info, :inverse_of => :product_supplier_info_packings
end
```

And I'm doing the following query:

```
rows = Product.includes(:product_supplier_infos => [:supplier, :product_supplier_info_packings])
```

It is making now 4 SQL queries.

If I add the following conditions

```
.where("product_supplier_infos.name = ?", "foobar")
```

it makes a LEFT OUTER JOIN on all the joined tables

Is there any way to make AR to make a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the included tables when not using conditions?

I also tried to use :joins(:product_supplier_infos => [:supplier, :product_supplier_info_packings]) which ends up with CROSS JOIN which I don't want and .joins(["LEFT OUTER JOIN product_supplier_infos...", "LEFT OUTER JOIN suppliers... ", "LEFT OUTER JOIN product_supplier_info_packings ..."]) but it didn't have any effect. I still got 4 SQL queries.

Comment: My immediate feeling is you could try to add .all to that Product.includes(...) statement, because .includes should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't have any effect. Still 4 SQL queries.

Comment: I used .all for this before but trying out that same code right now splits the queries, too. It's possible that AR tries to be smart about when to do joins and when it doesn't speed things up. I'll keep digging.

Comment: did you resolve your problem ?

Comment: No, unfortunately no :/ I just went with the additional queries, for now